# How to Write a Functional PHP that retrieves Interacts and returns Data from Database

Tags: php, function

I am new to functional Programming, having difficulty writing a function that could fetch and output a result from a specific database table. Below is the code I've tried already.

```
<?php
  function main()
  {
    $get = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tb_name");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($get) > 0) {
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($get);
      return json_encode($row);
    }
  }
?>
```

It seems not to work, Please any Idea how to get it working. Thanks :)

Comment: Quick and direct answer to such a broad and vague question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function select($table, $filter="", $order="", $limit="") {
$query = "SELECT * FROM " . $table . " WHERE 1 ";

if ($filter != "") {
    foreach($filter as $key => $value) {
        $query .= 'AND ' . $key . ' = "' . $value . '" ';
    }
}

if ( $order != "" ) {
    $query .= " ORDER BY ". $order;
}

if ( $limit != "" ) {
    $query .= " LIMIT ". $limit;
}

return mysql_query( $query );
```

}

Try using:

```
$filter = array(
    'field' => 'value'
);
$rs = select('table_name', $filter, 'id DESC', 3);
```

Return will be:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE 1 AND field = 'value' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3
```

You can adjust the function with your needs. Use **mysql_fetch_object** to loop through fields results.

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-fetch-object.php

Answer (score 1):

Have fun http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php  Do some quick reading about how to connect to a database, whatever one you use (MySQL, Postgres, etc) using PDO.

[Here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059) is a simple tutorial.